# Replace loop in Stata

Tags: replace, stata

I have two variables: patient id and date. Many patients on my database are duplicated. I want to keep the duplication, but apply to each patient the earliest appearing date.

Ex:

```
ID    Date
1     8/9/07
1     6/3/07
1     11/15/08
2     8/6/06
2     8/6/06
2     11/5/09
```

would become

```
ID    Date
1     6/3/07
1     6/3/07
1     6/3/07
2     8/6/06
2     8/6/06
2     8/6/06
```

Comment: You're being downvoted, I guess, because there is no code attempt here and the problem and its solution are well documented. I advise against appeals to urgency in forums like this. Your urgency is not ours, and you don't really mean to imply that other questions should get lower priority.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. I didn't mean to imply anything nor to offense anyone. I did search for 4-5 hours for an answer to my question. I guess now I am implying that I should learn how to search for stata questions...I had looked on the website you recommended but I'll look longer next time. Sorry.

Comment: All advice is intended in your best (long-term) interests. `search first date` in Stata does point to the FAQ in question. On the other hand `search earliest date` does not.  If you accept my answer, you will gain reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first date is just the minimum date. Sort dates within each patient, and the first date and the smallest date are one and the same, as a date is numeric.

```
bysort id (date) : gen firstdate = date[1]
```

Note that I deliberately did not overwrite your original date variable. First, if I messed up the code, I would need to read in the data all over again. Second, you might decide later that the dates were useful.

Learn about subscripting and the use of `by:`.

For one tutorial, see [here](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=pr0004).

For an FAQ dealing specifically with your question, see [here](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/generating-last-date/).